# Why WHM, New Relic and SSH memory usage statistics different?

Tags: centos, performance, vps

I have a Cent OS 6.4 Apache Nginx VPS. I have WHM cpanel. How do I check past 24 hours or 48 hours this server RAM usage?

I use new relic server monitor web application. It reported that, this VPS peak time RAM usage less than 30%. Also WHM service status shows similar figures. But when I'm contacting my VPS company, they mentioned that, it uses more than 95% RAM (peak time). I'm totally new to the server management.

**Updated!**

When I run `free -m` command, I receive following output. But at the same time WHM cPanel service status shows, Memory Used 16.88% (442,464 of 2,621,440). Also new relic shows similar statistics (Similar to the WHM).

```
root@host [~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2560       1117       1442          0          0        748
-/+ buffers/cache:        368       2191
Swap:            0          0          0
root@host [~]#
```

Comment: What is the reason for down vote?

Comment: Does this 'relic server monitor' tell you total RAM consumption? Or just active RAM use? It's important to note the difference as Linux tends to cache large volumes of stuff in RAM, but not 'actively use it'. This results in performance metrics than can appear skewed. (E.g. your server might be consuming 95% RAM but only actively using 30%). I know this isn't answering your actual question - but it could help explain the difference you're seeing. Help us out by posting the output of "free -m".

Comment: Yes Blacklinght, it shows overall statistics about the server. This is a wired issue. When I try free -m it shows total-2560 used-1117 free-1442. But WHM cPanel Service Status shows 338,696 of 2,621,440.

Comment: 338 megs of memory is used by actual programs/processes on your system.  748 megs is used to cache things like recently opened files.  The cache can go away without bad things happening.  If non-cache memory runs out, bad things happen (namely: processes start to get killed by the kernel until there's enough free memory again)

Comment: You mean `cached memory + actual programs/process memory=used memory (in SSH)` Therefore, WHM and new relic statistics and SSH statistics are same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, because cpanel makes it simple by not confusing people with things like cache (whose usage is not critical when trying to determine if we have enough ram to start, say, a process we know will consume 200 megs while running)

Comment: cPanel is only reporting used memory. (I.e. not counting your cached memory). Your VPS company must be looking at an active + cached metric. Which is why they're reporting higher ram consumption. This is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Solus or equivalent control panel with your VPS account?  Most VPS control panels provide 1-day memory usage graphs.  For example, with Solus (a popular VPS control panel), click on the "statistics" tab near the bottom of the control panel.

As an aside, if you would like to learn how to manage things without needing to depend on WHM cpanel, and are comfortable with learning how to use a command-line terminal, you are welcome to ask questions over at http://unix.stackexchange.com -- it's a smaller and tighter community than serverfault, with a lot of really experienced old-school UNIX gurus.

Comment: I have WHM. Its service status shows 338,696 of 2,621,440 and new relic also reporting same figures. But Muni service monitor and SSH shows more than 1GB RAM usage (same time). Thank you samiam your suggestion.

Comment: What is the exact output of `free` (edit and add this to the question)

Comment: just updated the question.